# Angular Form control is invalid on component init, without any action

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

On component init all the form controls with validators are marked as invalid without taking any actions.

`component.html`

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="phone" [class.error]="form.get('phone').invalid">
  <button type="submit">goo</button>
</form>
```

`component.ts`

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.form = this.fb.group({
          phone: [
              null,
              [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(9), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]
          ]
      });

      console.log(this.form);
  }

  submit() {
      if (this.form.invalid) return;

      console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tztih8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Put a [mre] in the question, not just an offsite link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other properties on the forms and form controls that you will want to look at. Given your question, I believe the following should fix your issue:

```html
    <form [formGroup]="form" >
      <input type="text" formControlName="phone" [class.error]="form.get('phone').invalid && form.get('phone').touched">
      <button type="submit">goo</button>
    </form>
```

The solution adds `form.get('phone').touched` to your `class.error` check. Since the blank page phone input fails your validator, it is marked as 'errored' even though it hasn't been touched. You could add the check for touched as well which will cause the form to not show the 'error' class upon load, but only after a user has visited that input and the value that is in it isn't valid.

Comment: Yeah, this could be the answer. But I have two previous projects, where I didn't have to check touched state, just `.invalid` or `.hasError()` did the trick, i.e. returned `true` only if user touched controls.

Answer (score 1):

Because your constraint `Validators.required`

You can `console.log(this.form.get('phone').value)` show `null` so that control invalid.

Should remove `[class.error]="form.get('phone').invalid"`